# Get a specific column of the updated rows

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc, prepared-statement

I need to know how to execute an update in JDBC with Oracle database backend and retrieve values for a specific column of the records that have been updated. The column that I am interested in is part of a composite primary key, e.g. `COL_NAME` in the example below.

I have tried the following:

```
String query = "UPDATE T1 SET COL_ABC = 'A'"; // Simplified
statement = conn.prepareStatement(query.toString(), new String[] { "COL_NAME" });
ResultSet rs = statement.getResultSet();
while (rs.next()) {
  rs.getLong("COL_NAME");
}
```

But `statement` comes back as `null`.

I am not sure how to utilize `RETURNING INTO` in this case unless converting this whole thing into an anonymous PL/SQL block, if it is indeed a possible solution.

Please note that I need a list of the values from this column from all the records that have been updated.

Comment: Did you try `UPDATE T1 SET COL_ABC = 'A'` followed by `SELECT COL_NAME FROM T1`, both in the same database transaction? As long as the `WHERE` clause is the same, you'll get the same result. If the column being updated is part of the `WHERE` clause, execute the `SELECT` first.

Comment: What do you mean with _But `statement` comes back as `null`."_? Either the prepare succeeds or it fails with an exception; it should never return `null`. Also, the generated keys result set must be retrieved with `getGeneratedKeys()`, not with `getResultSet()` (this is probably your actual problem). You're also not doing anything with the result of `getLong`...

Comment: @Andreas I gives `ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended` error. I even tried to add `;` to the end of `UPDATE` but same error.

Comment: @NuCradle I meant as two *different* prepared statements.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel When the code gets to `conn.prepareStatement(query.toString(), new String[] { "COL_NAME" });` it returns null to `statement` object. `getGeneratedKeys()` from what I can see is for `INSERT` that have auto-generated values. `COL_NAME` already have values and we are not generating anything new -- just updating a few unrelated columns. P.S. `getLong()` is just to check the values and will be handled once this issue is sorted out.

Comment: @Andreas Sorry didn't get back to you sooner. Your suggestion appears to work. Would you please put it as an answer so you'll be credited?

Comment: @NuCradle If that returns `null`, then either your driver is buggy, or the code shown is not your actual code (and for example swallows an exception in a catch-block. A `prepareStatement` call is never allowed to return `null`. It should either return a `PreparedStatement`, or throw an exception

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Thank you for the follow up. I just reported what I was seeing when the debugger executes `prepareStatement()` part and the `Statement` object gets dereferenced afterward. However, you are right about this that the documentations do not suggest that this method is going to return `null`. For the record, I am using Oracle 12.1 driver with Oracle 12.1 DB. (side note: I don't think the SQL itself was bad or else I should have gotten `SQLException`)